# Drupal How to change access denied / login page for one protected page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have one page ( a view page ) where I need the user to be logged-in in order to see it. But the default login page seems overly harsh and would want to a friendlier page in page stating the need to sign up to see this portion of the website.

My quick thought was the create a module that put a hook in for this particular page of the site. But I am not sure that this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'friendlier' page you mean some text stating need to "sign up to see this portion of the website", it would be better to

either

- use hook_form_alter to add a markup field for text

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#markup

or

- simply create a block and set its visibility to [show only on following pages] : "user/login"